# Using RESTapi to connect to TFS online from code

Tags: c#, .net, json, tfs

I am trying to get access to my projects in TFS online from my C# code in order to get all the data about builds, tasks, projects etc. with the RESTapi, I have been following the documentation available online to do so (http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/get-started/get-started-rest-basics-vsi), however, when I want to get the Json response from the url, I always get: HTTP code 203: Non-Authoritative Information, and therefore I am not able to get the Json data. If I try to get the response using POSTMAN (chrome extension) I get an HTTP code 200 and the data I need.

This is my code:

```
public static async void GetBuilds()
    {
        try
        {
            var username = "userTest";
            var password = "PassTest";

            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                    new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic",
                    Convert.ToBase64String(
                        System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
                            string.Format("{0}:{1}", username, password))));

                using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(
                            "https://myproject.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/build/builds?api-version=1.0-preview.1").Result)
                {
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                    string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    Console.WriteLine(responseBody);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

I always get in the response a high amount of HTML but nothing close to what I need, what am I doing wrong?

Many thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Did you try running their full example (just hard code your username / password if you want)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code seems correct to me. Have you enabled alternate credentials for your VSO account? It won't work without it. Here's the [link](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/get-started/get-started-auth-introduction-vsi) explaining how to do it.

You can also check out my project on the codeplex: https://vsorest.codeplex.com/ It shows how to use some of the VSO REST APIs using C#

Comment: You are right, I had to enable the alternate credentials, now I am getting the data, thanks a lot for your help and for sharing your project!